# Getting swagger-ui to display my codegen-generated API

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, springfox

I'm working on a springboot project. We're doing API first so we're generating code from an api.yaml. We're using openapi 3.0. The interfaces are being generated fine but when we browse to our swagger-ui URL, it says No operations defined in spec!

Here are the details:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

  private final BuildProperties buildProperties;

  @Bean
  public Docket docketConfig() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
            .basePackage("com.xyz.infrastructure.rest.spring.resource"))
        .build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
  }

  private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
        .title(buildProperties.getName())
        .version(buildProperties.getVersion())
        .build();
  }
}
```

Our structure is:

com.xyz.infrastructure.rest.spring
|
|- config
|- SwaggerConfig
|- spec //autogenerated
|- dto //autogenerated
|- resource // implementations of interfaces found in spec

What are we missing?

We're using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-codegen</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally got it to work. Here's what did it for us:

Springfox version 3:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Using the io.swagger.codegen.v3 plugin.

This swagger config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOpenApi
public class SwaggerConfig {

  @Bean
  public Docket docketConfig() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
            .basePackage("com.xyz.infrastructure.rest.spring.resource"))
        .build();
  }

}
```

And make sure your classes in resource have the @RestController annotation.

Answer (score -1):

I used like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                //.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("uz.xb.qr_project"))//*** base package
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaData());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Spring Boot REST API")
                .description("\"Spring Boot REST API for Online Store\"")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
                .contact(new Contact("John Thompson", "https://springframework.guru/about/", "john@springfrmework.guru"))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")//**address of swagger ui
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");


        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

ApiController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    private ApiService apiService;

    @GetMapping
    public String swagger(){
        return "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                "<html lang=\"en\">\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" +
                "    <title>REST API LIST</title>\n" +
                "    <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=/qr_online/swagger-ui.html\" />\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<a href=\"qr_online/swagger-ui.html\">REST API LIST</a>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>";
    }

  //Or you can use like this inside controller
  /*
    @GetMapping
    public void redirect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("swagger-ui.html");
    }
  */

}
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```